# Alias multiple distinct_id to user in Mixpanel

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mixpanel

I have implemented the Mixpanel IAM workflow in the following manner

- When a user attempts to signup, I send the `distinct_id=1`  to the server and if the signup succeeds I `mixpanel.alias(distinct_id=1, username=user1)` in the back (username is unique)
- When the user successfully logs in, I `mixpanel.identify(username=user1)` to merge the anonymous events to user events in the front
- When the user logs out, I `mixpanel.reset()` to clear the cookies in the front

Now after logging out, mixpanel uses a new `distinct_id=2` for the new session. All the events from the anonymous user are linked to the new `distinct_id=2`. But now, if I log in, all future events will be linked to the correct user `username=1`. What I would need, in theory, is to be able to alias multiple `distinct_id` to a username/my own unique id but that is specifically discouraged and it also doesn't work. Because otherwise I would have something like this

1. Anonymous event - `distinct_id=1`
2. Sign up event - `distinct_id=1|username=1`
3. Log in event - `distinct_id=1|username=1`
4. Log out event - `distinct_id=1|username=1`
5. Anonymous event - `distinct_id=2`
6. Log in event - `distinct_id=1|username=1`

and I would be losing the batch(5) of anonymous events

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Note that Mixpanel's new identity management system (Identity Merge) handles this scenario automatically. You no longer Alias. Just Identify when the user signs in or up, and Mixpanel will associate multiple anonymous IDs with the same identified user.

https://help.mixpanel.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039133851-Moving-to-Identity-Merge

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, Mixpanel handles all distinct IDs itself and you only call 
mixpanel.identify(user_id) when user signs-in or mixpanel.alias(user_id) when user signs-up.

No need to handle anything, mixpanel will track all events with random user id which prevails when user signs-out.

https://help.mixpanel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004509426-Distinct-ID-Creation-JavaScript-iOS-Android-

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reverse the order of params you pass to alias() instead of `mixpanel.alias(distinct_id=1, username=user1)`. Do `mixpanel.alias( username=user1, distinct_id=1)`.

I think their documentation is kind of misleading.